# how to dynamic "_or" in filter query sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I'm a beginner at using `scrape` and `sqlalchemy` and I discovered a problem in this filter query.

```
data = ['foo','bar']
q_cat = self.session.query(Category).filter_by(_or(name=='foo',name=='bar')).all()
```

The data variable in my code is dynamic. How to make it dynamic inside `_or(...)` as well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you wish to search if the category falls into any of the data elements. In that case, its best to use `in_`. Here is an example.

```
Category.query.filter(Category.name.in_(data))
```

This will give you a list of all the categories with the names present in `data`.

Comment: My problem: The data variable is dynamic. :). I just example this code

Comment: I fail to understand your problem, why not just do `data[0]`. Just use the list's index.

Comment: i don't understand. I want to get all Category.name = 'foo' or 'bar'. How to use data[0] to resolve it. pls expain more.

Comment: @VoTue I think what you're looking for is in my second code example. Instead of using `_or` you use `_in`, because you're trying to filter the names in `data`.

Comment: @VoTue Happy to help. I just wish I could understand the problem quicker. I think it'd help if you'd define what you meant when you said dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply doing all *equals* operations, then then *in*_ operator would be the best to use.

However, if you really want to the *or_* and *and_* operators explicitly, both take an arbitrary number of clauses.

If your data list can vary in length, you can create a new list of the logical clauses that will be used for the *or_*, something like:

```
data = ['foo','bar']
data_comparisons = [Category.name == field for field in data]
q_cat = self.session.query(Category).filter_by(*data_comparisons).all()
```