# Sqlalchemy dynamic filtering of multiple options

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy, I want to query the following SQL-Statement for table 'Tab1' with a column 'Col1':

```
Select *
from Tab1 
where Tab1.Col1 == value1 or Tab1.Col1 == value2
```

'value1' and 'value2' come from a list which is potentially longer and dynamic.

Following the answer in here [how to dynamic "_or" in filter query sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29701327/how-to-dynamic-or-in-filter-query-sqlalchemy) I use the following code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker


engine = create_engine(...)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)

with Session() as session:
     data = ['value1', 'value2']
     data_comparisons = [Tab1.Col1 == field for field in data]
     q_cat = session.query(Tab1).filter_by(*data_comparisons).all()
```

I get however the error message:

```
TypeError: filter_by() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Does anybody have an idea what is wrong and how this could be implemented?

Comment: You are likely mixing up `filter()` and `filter_by()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the comparisons to the `or_` function and it will create an expression that will evaluate to `COMPARISON0 OR COMPARISON1 OR ...`

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import or_

q_cat = session.query(Tab1).filter(or_(*data_comparisons)).all()
```

Although if you are just using equality then I think `in_` might be better:

```py
q_cat = session.query(Tab1).filter(Tab1.Col1.in_(data)).all()
```